# Developer option gets ignored on restart - sony xperia xz1 compact

Tags: android, sony, developer-tools, sony-xperia

I just recently purchased an Xperia XZ1 compact, and came across a small quirk in the developer options. I use one of the rendering options to switch the phone to black/white (color blind?) instead of full color.

When I restart the phone, it switches back to full color, even though in the developer options says that it's in black/white (i.e. the option is ignored). To set the phone back into black and white, I have to switch the option off and on again.

Before this phone I had an Xperia z5 compact, which didn't have this issue.

NB. The phone's language is in Dutch, if that matters.

Comment: Is it Android? Maybe you can get some help on https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes it's android, and on the Sony developer support forum they advised posting here on SO. https://developer.sony.com/posts/get-developer-support-from-sony-engineers-on-stack-overflow/

Comment: Ok, makes sense